# Display items in MYSQL table from bottom to top

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to make an app that displays images in a feed form... images from the database are loaded 3 at a time from the top(first) row but i want it to display items in the database from bottom to top since newly inserted items go to bottom of the list... how can I load the table in reverse order? So it displays the rows from the bottom of the database table to the top of the table.

Here is my code... All in the file called "Chat.php"

```
<?php 
      //Getting the page number which is to be displayed  
      $page = $_GET['page']; 

     //Initially we show the data from 1st row that means the 0th row 
     $start = 0; 

 //Limit is 3 that means we will show 3 items at once
 $limit = 3; 

 //Importing the database connection 
 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 //Counting the total item available in the database 
 $total = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id from feed "));

 //We can go atmost to page number total/limit
 $page_limit = $total/$limit; 

 //If the page number is more than the limit we cannot show anything 
 if($page<=$page_limit){

 //Calculating start for every given page number 
 $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 

 //SQL query to fetch data of a range 
 $sql = "SELECT * from feed limit $start, $limit";

 //Getting result 
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

 //Adding results to an array 
 $res = array(); 

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 array_push($res, array(
 "name"=>$row['name'],
 "publisher"=>$row['publisher'],
 "image"=>$row['image'])
 );
 }
 //Displaying the array in json format 
 echo json_encode($res);
 }else{
            echo "over";
    }
```

Comment: `ORDER BY DESC` on your queries.

Comment: use `ORDER BY field DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//SQL query to fetch data of a range 
 $sql = "SELECT * from feed limit $start, $limit";
```

update these line like

```
 //SQL query to fetch data of a range 
 $sql = "SELECT * from feed ORDER BY 'feed .id' DESC limit  $start, $limit";
```